# How do you convince your manager that your project needs a huge refactoring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have joined a rails project as a contractor. The project has been going for more than a year. The code is written by about 10 different developers and most of them are contractors as well. They have different code style. Some of them came from Java. The code has horrible scores with metric_fu. Many functions are very long (100 - 300 lines). Some functions have insane amount of logical branches, loops, and recursions. Each request generates a ton of sql queries. Performance is very bad. Many obsolete code that are never used but never got the chance to be cleaned up. The core architecture is plain wrong or over engineered. Code coverage is only about 25%. Views and partials are chaotic and terrible to read and understand.

The manager is in a position trying to satisfy the CEO by continuously adding new features, however newer features are increasingly hard to get implemented correctly without breaking something else. He knows the code is bad, but doesn't want to put too much effort in fixing them as refactoring will take too long.

As a contractor / developer, what is a good way to clear this situation and convenience the Manager or CEO to partition some time for refactoring?

**Related Questions**

[How can I convince skeptical management and colleagues to allow refactoring of awful code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144/how-can-i-convince-skeptical-management-and-colleagues-to-allow-refactoring-of-aw)

[How to refactor on a budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737671/how-to-refactor-on-a-budget)

[Dealing with illogical managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497234/dealing-with-illogical-managers)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my limited experiance:

1. It's impossible to convince a manager that it's necessary to set aside time to refactor. You can make him aware of it, and reinforce the point every time that you run into an issue because of bad code. Then just move on. Hopefully your boss will figure it out.
2. It's quite common to get in on a running project and think "this is total junk". Give it some time. You might begin to see a pattern in the madness.

Comment: Ad. 2 - It happens every time to me, when I join a project. +1

Comment: Also ad 2: It happens almost every time to me when I resume working on parts of my own code I have not touched for a while ;-)

Comment: Unless you do something drastic and unrecommended like threatening bodily harm, this is what you're going to get. You'll have to manipulate the situation to refactor modules and convince them management bit by bit to give you enough power to make your large changes.

Comment: about #2, bad code is easy to write, and of course that copy and paste evolve into a pattern

Answer (score 2):

I've been in similar situation. There are basically only two options:

- You get some relaxed time and you may be granted time to refactor something
- Due to the bad code further development of some component comes to a stall. You can't proceed to add anything because every little change causes everything else to stop functioning. In this emergency case you will get a "go" with refactoring.

I have just answered in some other question, my horror story:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333077/dirty-coding-tricks-to-deliver-project-on-time/1333095#1333095

> I have worked on a project where dirty tricks were the main driving principle of the development. Needlees to say, after some time these tricks have started to conflict with each other. In one analytics component, we had to implement the other very dirty trick - to hide away those calculated values which due to the conflicting tricks were not calculated properly. Afterward, the second level tricks started to conflict and we had to create tricks to deal with those. Ever since, even the mentioning of this component makes me feel horror that I may have to work on it again.

It's exactly the second situation where refactoring is the only way out.

In general, many managers without a technical background (actually, those who come from bad programmers as well) neither care nor understand the value of quality code and good architecture. You can't make them listen until something interrupts their plans, like a blow of "non-implementable" features, increasing and reoccurring bugs, customer requests that cannot be satisfied and so on. Only then understanding of the code problems may come for the first time. Usually, it's too late by then.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is missing a point here:

> **Refactoring is part of the software development life cycle.**

this is not only a RoR or any specific project but any other software development project.

If somehow you could convince your PM [why it is important to refactor](http://www.google.com/search?q=why+refactor) the existing code base before adding any new feature, you're done. You should clearly tell your PM that any further addition of new feature without any refactoring will take more time than required. And even if the feature is added, somehow, bug resolving sessions will take even more time since the code is very bloat and unmaintainable.

I really don't understand why people forget the principle of optimise later. Optimising later also includes refactor later IMHO.

One more thing, when taking design decisions, you should tell the consequences, good or bad, to your PM very very clearly.

You can create a different branch(I assume you are using git) for refactoring and start adding new feature in some other branch if your PM insist on adding new feature along with refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring code that sucks is part of coding, so you don't need to get anybody's approval **unless your manager is watching your code and or hours VERY closely.** The time I save refactoring today is time that I don't have to bill doing mad tricks to get normal code to work tomorrow (so it works out, in the end).

Busting up methods into smaller methods and deleting methods that are not used is part of your job. Reducing DB calls, in code that you call, is also necessary so that your code doesn't suck. Again, not really refactoring, just normal coding.

Convincing your manager depends on other factors, including (but not limited to) their willingness to be convinced, and your ability to convince.

Anyway, what is massive refactoring in RoR? Even if the "core architecture is just plain wrong," it can usually be straightened out a bit at a time. Make sure you break it into chunks /use branches so you don't break anything while you're busy fixing.

If this is impossible, then you come back to the social question of how to convince your manager. That's a simple question of figuring out what his/her buttons are, and pushing them without getting fired nor arrested. Shaming, withholding food, giving prizes, being a friend, anonymous kidnapping threats where you step in and save the day... It's pretty simple, really: creativity is the key!

Answer (score 1):

A tricky one, i have recently worked in such a company... they were always pushing for new things, again they knew it was bad, but no matter how hard I pushed it - i even got external consultants in to verify my findings - they seen it as a waste of time.

Eventually they seen the light... it only took multiple server crashes and at one point almost a full 8 days of no website to convince them.

Even at that they insisted it 'must' be the hosting service.

The key is to try and quantify how long their site will last before it crunches, and get some external verification to back you up - 'they' always trust outsiders who know nothing about your app! Also, try - if you can - to give a plan that involves gradual replacement at worst, and a plan for how long it would take to do that way. Also a plan for if 1 or 2 bodies were working on a complete rewrite hwo long it might take - but be realistic too or it will bit you in the bum! If you go that route (which is what we done) you can still have some work on the existing site as long as you incorporate it into the new.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put focus on things that they can see for themselves, that is, they will surely notice that the application is slow in some functionalities, so pick up one of them and say something like "I can reduce the waiting time here, can I take some time to improve this specific thing?" (more well said, but you got the point :P).

Also consider that 10 developers before you did not refactor the code base, this may mean that it is a monstruos task, likely to make the situation worse, in this situation if something will go wrong after the refactoring it will be your fault if the program does not work properly anymore.
Just a though, but worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take one small chunk of application and refactored and optimized it 'till it shines (and I'd do it in my personal time in order not to annoy my manager). Then you'll be able to show your manager/CEO the good results of refactoring and SQL optimizations.

Comment: No, you shouldn't work for free.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a need to refactor then the code will speak for itself. Minor refactoring can continue in during development. If you cant convince the manager then probably you should rethink if its necessary at all.

However if it is absolutely necessary then constructing metrics of development activities and the benefits should convince the manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of options would be to highlight to the manager how re-factoring the code base now will save time  (i.e. money) in the long-run. If the project is expecting to be running long term then making the changes now will clearly save you and other developers time in the future.

Best to use an example of a feature you've worked on estimating how long it would have taken if you had the cleaner code to work from in the first place. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am in same position right now, but with an agreement with the manager that, when the new feature should be implemented in some existing module to re-factor the module too (if it needs re-factoring), we are struggling now with the code created 4-5 years ago and definitely I find out that the re-factoring someone else s code is not trivial nor amusing to do, but very very helpful for the future re-use.